# what is the best application to access data base ( mysql or other) with angular cli.?

Tags: mysql, angular

This is my first experience with angular and i dont now where i have to find !

Comment: You don't typically access your database directly from Javascript - you would generally communicate via an API that handles security and business logic. Even if you did communicate directly with your database, that database would need to be exposed over http(s), and you would query it using the `HttpClient` like any other API.

Comment: You can use Firestore if you don't have experience with writing your own API, it's pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Yes i found a tutorial video about firebase( in french :-))  . I think is better from my point of view.